# Github API sorting search results by the created_at field

Tags: api, github, github-api

How can I create a search query sorted by the `created_at` field? I've tried:

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=blog&sort=created_at&order=desc
```

and

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=blog&sort=created&order=desc
```

But I get the same results as this query:

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=blog
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `sort` parameter [only takes one of three values](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories): `stars`, `forks` or `updated`:

> The sort field. One of `stars`, `forks`, or `updated`. Default: results are sorted by best match.

It doesn't appear to be possible to sort by creation date, but you could read the response of the search query into an array and sort from there.

Comment: I've got  request like   
 `req = requests.get(
        'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=' + q + '&sort=created' +
        '&order=desc' + '?access_token=' + ACCESS_TOKEN)`  and now how may I sort it?

Comment: You will need to use `req.get_json()` to obtain the returned payload—use something like `sorted(req.get_json()['items'], key=lambda x: x['created_at'])` to get the results sorted by creation date (I haven't tested this, but it should get you somewhere near where you'd like to be).

Comment: `sorted(req.json()['items'], key=lambda x: x['created_at'])` get the results

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what was written till now I found out [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories) another way. 
That is:

```
https://api.github.com/users/<user name>/repos?sort=created&direction=desc
```

For example:

```
https://api.github.com/users/nadar71/repos?sort=created&direction=desc
```