# Sort github API list repos by created_at date

Tags: sorting, github-api

I am using the
[github developer API link](https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=oauth&order=asc)  to list all the repositories with given search term and I want to sort it by `created_at` date in descending order. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself:
Listing repos with given search term (eg. oauth):

```
response = https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=oauth&order=desc
```

Now sort it as

```
# Sort based on created_at date 
data = sorted(response.json()['items'], key=lambda x: x['created_at'], reverse = True)
```

Thanks to [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40762518/github-api-sorting-search-results-by-the-created-at-field)

Comment: Sorting after the fact is not the same as getting the API to sort it for you.