# Can I list Github's public repositories using GraphQL?

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I am trying to list public repositories in Github using **GraphQL** as it allows me to choose exactly which information from an `Object` I want.

Using **REST** I could list public repositories simply by making requests to `https://api.github.com/repositories`. This is OK, but the response comes with a bunch of stuff I don't need. So, I was wondering if I could use **GraphQL** to do the same job.

The problem is, I couldn't find any high level repositories `Object` I could use to list public repositories using **GraphQL**. For me it seems I can only use **GraphQL** to list repositories from organizations or from users. For example, like doing so:

```
query{
    user(login: "someuser"){
        repositories(first: 50){
            nodes{
                name
            }
            pageInfo{
                hasNextPage
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, how can I use (if at all) Github's GraphQL endpoint to list Github's public repositories?

I have also tried something on this line, using `search`, but I doubt Github has only 54260 repositories as the `repositoryCount` variable returned me.

```
query{
    search(query:"name:*", type:REPOSITORY, first:50){
        repositoryCount
        pageInfo{
            endCursor
            startCursor
        }
        edges{
            node{
                ... on Repository{
                    name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Learned so much in the last few days about GraphQL that I summarized my endeavor with a post on Medium: https://medium.com/@fabiomolinar/using-githubs-graphql-to-retrieve-a-list-of-repositories-their-commits-and-some-other-stuff-ccbbb4e96d78

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `is:public` in the search query :

```graphql
{
  search(query: "is:public", type: REPOSITORY, first: 50) {
    repositoryCount
    pageInfo {
      endCursor
      startCursor
    }
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20search(query%3A%20%22is%3Apublic%22%2C%20type%3A%20REPOSITORY%2C%20first%3A%2050)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20repositoryCount%0A%20%20%20%20pageInfo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20endCursor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20startCursor%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Repository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: One more question, would it be possible to order the results by date it was created?

Comment: @FTM you can't sort by creation date in search query, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40764448/2614364). You can only sort by creation date when requesting user repositories in the `repositories` connection, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47255971/2614364)

Comment: thank you once again. Final question, where can I find more information about what can I use to form my search query? I tried Github's documentation about its Repository object, but it says nothing about things like "is:public" or any other arguments I could use on the search query.

Comment: You can find it [here](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories/#search-based-on-whether-a-repository-is-private-or-public) for search options & [here](https://help.github.com/articles/sorting-search-results/) for sorting

Comment: Bertrand, if you were my neighbor I would definitely pay some beers for you! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There is also an inPrivate attribute on the Repository object you can query
https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#repository